# JPA Mapping - Unique combination of parents per child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using:
Spring 3.2
Hibernate 4.1.9

I need to map, with JPA, three classes.  Class A has a ManyToMany relationship with Class B.  A unique combination of Class A and Class B need to own a collection of Class C.

**Table A**

```
foo
id | name
```

**Table B**

```
bar
id | name
```

**Table C**

```
data
id | xrefId
```

**Join Table** -- *Unique Key on (fooId,barId)*

```
xref
id | fooId | barId
```

Altering the existing data structure is not an option.

Edit 1:

Goal: Load a Foo, get its collection of Bars.  From each Bar, get its (their!) collection of Data.

**Class A**

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @ManyToMany(optional = false)
  @JoinTable(name               = "xref",
             joinColumns        = { @JoinColumn(name = "fooId") },
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "barId") })
  private List<Bar> lstBar = new ArrayList<Bar>();
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class Bar {
  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "lstBar")
  private List<Foo> lstFoo = new ArrayList<Foo>();
}
```

**Class C**

```
public class Data {
  @Id
  private UUID id;
}
```

Comment: So how far have you gotten?  Can you show us some code where you need some help?

Comment: I have added where I am currently at.  I do not know where / how to relate Class C ("Data") to the unique combination of Foo / Bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just KISS. Make another class Xref, which contains `id`, `foo`, `bar` and `Set<Data>` fields. Make a DAO method to find an Xref using two parameters `foo` and `bar` (implement it with a simple HQL). The unique requirement could be achieved by an unique constraint in the database.

It doesn't look good trying to express it just by the class hierarchy, better to use DAOs.

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  I was trying to avoid this, but it is the only answer I can come up with.  The fact that it is here (twice, even) reinforces that.

Answer (score 0):

Your join table, `xref`, has an extra `id` field, in order to be able to create such a table with JPA you need an extra entity class `XRef` and then you have to map the relation between `A` and `XRef` and betweem `B` and `XRef` (both are one-to-many). Then, you can create the entity class `C` and map the relation between `C` and `XRef`. Do you need more help? I don't have time right now to provide the code, but if you need ask and I will try to add it as soon as possible.

Comment: This answer is the same as the previous answer.  I know you guys had to have submitted them within seconds.  Not that either is any more or less correct than the other...I have to "accept" the other because its first.

Comment: No problem Mike! By the time I submitted my answer kan's was already there :D

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example (used Integer instead of UUID for simplicity, the rest should be OK).

**Bar class:**

```
public class Bar {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "barId")
    private Collection<Xref> xrefCollection;
}
```

**Foo class:**

```
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fooId")
    private Collection<Xref> xrefCollection;
}
```

**Xref  class:**

```
public class Xref {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "xrefId")
    private Collection<Data> dataCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Bar barId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Foo fooId;
}
```

**Data Class:**

```
public class Data {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "xref_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Xref xrefId;
}
```

This code has been [automatically generated by NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html), provided that all tables and indexes are correctly defined in the DB